# Troubles Setting up Private Stellar Network

Tags: stellar-core, private-network

I am trying to setup a stellar private network for experimentation purposes. Unfortunately, no matter what i do, the nodes end up not being able to sync up. Mostly, as soon as I change the network name, things fall apart.

The step by step instructions that I follow are documented here:

```
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Zu8_0ZsXOisYsMh8lHITkMeaOXmojW8EkAqix_eEVCI
```

I will truly appreciate ANY help. ANY! It seems many more things have to be done when the pass phrase is changed. But I can't figure out what are those things.

Comment: Did you already manage to run the first node in standalone mode? Does it have status Synced? Are the history archives available? IP adresses correct? Can node2 access https://http://172.17.0.2/history/.well-known/stellar-history.json ? Do you get any suspicious error messages? You have to use the same network name from the very begining, you must not change it afterwards - start over with a clean db with `stellar-core new-db`.